# Retrieve data from nested json using python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to retrieve data from multiple nested json and put it in csv file. The code is:

```
    for script in scripts:
    if 'offerInfo' in script.text:
        offer_data = script.text[144:][:-1]
        json_data = json.loads(offer_data)
        if str(id) not in json_data['data']:
            return
        offer_name = json_data['data'][str(id)]['offerName']
        offer_price = json_data['data'][str(id)]['price']
        offer_terms = ('https:' + json_data['data'][str(id)]['terms'][0])
        package_products = json_data['data'][str(id)]['products'][1]['name']
        return [id, offer_name, offer_price, offer_terms, offer_products ]
```

It works, but problem is, that some json files are incomplete and miss field that i try to retreive. In that case it ends with `IndexError: list index out of range`. How i can change it to just to ignore missing fields?

Here is sample of json file:

```
{
"list":[
"55"
],
"data":{
"55":{
"id":"55",
"offerName":"Offer 55",
"products":[
{
"name":"Product 1",
"type":"software",
"category":"Internet",
"id":"Product_1",
"description":"Product 1 description":[
"\/\/www.url.com\/products\/product_1_description.pdf"
]
},
{
"name":"Product 2",
"type":"",
"category":"hardware",
"id":"Product 2",
"description":"Product 2 description",
"documents":[
"\/\/www.url.com\/products\/product_2_description.pdf"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify your code with a try/except block and therefor ignore any errors thrown by your script, though I do not advise to do if the circumstances were different.

```
for script in scripts:
    if 'offerInfo' in script.text:
        offer_data = script.text[144:][:-1]
            try:
                json_data = json.loads(offer_data)
                if str(id) not in json_data['data']:
                    return
                offer_name = json_data['data'][str(id)]['offerName']
                offer_price = json_data['data'][str(id)]['price']
                offer_terms = ('https:' + json_data['data'][str(id)]['terms'][0])
                package_products = json_data['data'][str(id)]['products'][1]['name']
                return [id, offer_name, offer_price, offer_terms, offer_products ]
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

This way it will just skip any entries that are not present.

Comment: Thx for response. That works only partially, because when there  at least  one field is missing, all other are skiped. Fe.: When there is json only with 'offerName' and 'price', but without 'terms' just want to write to csv offername nad price and skip terms. With your solution, when thee is my field missing, nothing is written to csv.